# In SO Careers, can the profile list be a dropdown?

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, jobs

[image]

Look at that list. Could it be a dropdown list? That makes things easier to use:

[image]

Otherwise we need to scroll all the way down, if we have many accounts.

Example: (Not everything)

```js
siteNum = 1;

sites = ["StackOverflow", "Meta StackExchange", "Health StackExchange", "Blender StackExchange", "Super User", "Drulpal Answers", "Chess StackExchange", "Beer StackExchange", "Coffee StackExchange", "Chemistry StackExchange"];

function includes(arr, obj) {
  return (arr.indexOf(obj) != -1);
}

function newSite() {
  ++siteNum;
  siteID = $('<SPAN>');
  siteID.html('Site ' + siteNum + ': ');
  siteSelect = $('<SELECT>');
  sites.forEach(function(e) {
    site = $('<OPTION>');
    site.html(e);
    siteSelect.append(site);
  });
  div = $('<DIV>');
  siteSelect.attr('id', 'siteListSelect-' + siteNum);
  div.append(siteID);
  div.append(siteSelect);
  div.attr('id', 'siteList-' + siteNum);
  $('#siteLists').append(div);
}

function done() {
  chosen = [];
  for (p = 1; p <= siteNum; ++p) {
    site = $('#siteListSelect-' + p + ' option:selected').html();
    if (!includes(chosen, site))
      chosen.push(site);
  }

  chosen.forEach(function(e) {
    alert('Site: ' + e)
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="siteLists">
  <div id="siteList-1">
    <span>Site 1:</span>
    <select id="siteListSelect-1">
      <option>StackOverflow</option>
      <option>Meta StackExchange</option>
      <option>Health StackExchange</option>
      <option>Blender StackExchange</option>
      <option>Super User</option>
      <option>Drupal Answers</option>
      <option>Chess StackExchange</option>
      <option>Beer StackExchange</option>
      <option>Cofee StackExchange</option>
      <option>Chemistry StackExchange</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>


<button onclick="newSite()">Add New Site</button>
<button onclick="done()">Done!</button>
```

Of course, it would remove already selected sites.

Comment: And you don't mind to lose the ability to select multiple sites?

Comment: @PatrickHofman Hmmm, I'm making an example to show how it works

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Stack Overflow has [discontinued](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/415293) Stack Overflow Jobs and Developer Story on March 31, 2022.

Answer (score 6):

I do think the 'problem' should be solved, but I don't think the list should be a drop-down. Most users don't have such an excessive list of communities.

An option that would make this better I think is that the list is narrowed down to the communities that you have actually asked or answered questions on. (I see a lot of 101 reputation accounts, probably for flagging, etc.) The rest can be put in a part that is collapsed, so they are accessible in the end.

This will narrow down your list to 11 communities.

Answer (score 4):

Agree this isn't the optimal UI for linking Stack Exchange accounts - it's incredibly unwieldy. Will keep this in mind as we revisit UI changes again in the future.

Comment: Jon, please consider changing/removing the status tag.